# Gradient effect to background image

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to achive a view like this. As you can see there is a gradient effect to background image. To do this i tried following code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_background"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient" />
```

And this is gradient.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#00202239"
        android:startColor="#aa202239"
        android:centerColor="#00202239" />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    </shape>
```

Result:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, so the exact problem is that the gradient isn't rendered properly?

Comment: Yep, it is not rendering properly. I want  something like that in first screenshot.

Comment: Surprising. Its rendered properly on my side.

Comment: Could you send me a screenshot?

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/zgtZf). I used the same layout of `<ImageView>` as yours.